# Unable to fetch data from database using ajax function Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to fetch data from the database using ajax call, but my function in jquery is not working for fetching the data and I am getting an error "data is not defined". I don't know what goes wrong. I am trying to fetch all data from the database table and display it on the screen  Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use App\Models\patient;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class SearchPatient extends Controller
{
    
    function action(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            $query= $request->get('query');
            if ($query != '')
            {
                $data = DB::table('patients')->first()
                ->where('patientid','like','%'.$query.'%' )
                ->orWhere('fname','like','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('lname','like','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('contactno','like','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('gender','like','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('cnic','like','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('city','like','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('address','like','%'.$query.'%')
                ->get();
            }
            else
            {
                $data = DB::table('patients')->first()
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
            }
            $total_row = $data->count();
            if($total_row > 0)
            {
                foreach($data as $row)
                {
                    $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                             '.$row->patientid.'
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        '.$row->fname.'
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        '.$row->lname.'
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        '.$row->cnic.'
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        '.$row->gender.'
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        '.$row->address.'
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        '.$row->contactno.'
                        </td>



                        <td>
                        '.$row->city.'
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        '.$row->created_at.'
                        </td>
                    
                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $output='
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="5"> 
                    No Data Found
                    </td>
                </tr>';
            }
            $data = array(
                'table_data'   =>  $output,
                'table_data'   =>  $table_data
            );

            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    fetch_patients('');

    function fetch_patients(query = '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            URL:"/action",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {query:query},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
                $('total-patient-records').text(data.total_data);

            }
        })
    }


    $(document).on('keyup', '#searchpatient', function(){
        var query = $(this).val();
        fetch_patients(query);
    })
});
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/action',  [SearchPatient::class, 'action'])->name('action');


Route:: get ('/SearchPatient',function(){
    return view ('SearchPatient');
});
```

Here is my blade file

```
<div class="container box">
    <h3 align="center">Search Patient</h3><BR>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            Search Patient Data
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <input type="text" name="searchpatient" id="searchpatient" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Patient">           
          </div>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <h3 align="center">Total Data : <span id="total-patient-records"></span></h3>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Patient ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>CNIC</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Contact No</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Last Visit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>


                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: Error I am getting]

Comment: There's a lot of parts here where it could go wrong. Open up your browser's developer console, and check the Console tab when you run the query. Are there any errors there? Check the Network tab, and click on the request that's made. Are you getting a proper response?

Comment: can you show me the Error response as a Screen short?

Comment: @UmerRasheed I have attached the error ss.

Comment: @aynber no, I am not getting any response in the network tab however I am getting errors in the console and I have attached that image in edited code.

Comment: Where is `data` coming from in `fetch_patients(data);`? You're calling the function as soon as the document loads and passing a parameter that does not appear to have been defined.

Comment: @Peppermintology from the controller

Comment: @UmerRasheed I know that but what's the solution?

Comment: @Peppermintology yes as I want to show all the table data as the document loads

Comment: Your controller returns `ajax` *after* it has been called. You're code is telling you it can't even make that call because `data` is `undefined`. Provide an initial value in your method argument or just remove `data` from the first `fetch_patiens()` as you have a default value in the method signature anyway.

Comment: @Peppermintology i did it but still not fetching the data

Comment: Does removing `data` resolve the error though?

Comment: @Peppermintology yes, but it's still not getting data from DB.

Comment: So what errors (if any) do you get now? I don't have a crystal ball, we need **you** to provide **as much debugging information as possible in order to help you**.

Comment: @Peppermintology this time I am not getting any error, I am also getting 200 status in the network but it's not fetching the data.

Comment: Then consider your `patients` query might not be returning any data. You will need to debug your code and step through it. Only you can do that though. Add in some `dd()` statements in your `action` and see what your `$query` and `$data` variables hold at certain points.

Comment: @Peppermintology getting nothing in response.

Comment: You will need to debug your code and step through it. Only you can do that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = '{{ route('get_products') }}';
var data = {
   "_token": $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          };
$.ajax({
 type: "get",
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: function(response) {
        alert(response.data);            
  }
});




<------ controller ------>

public function get_products()
{
   $data =   DB::table('products)->get();
   return response()->json(['data' => $products]);
}
```

Comment: In this way, create a clean ajax action and check it out.

Comment: kindly use my code if you can debug it as I am not getting any errors but also not fetching the data as the document loads.

Comment: dd(); Check your controller part by using it, but the problem seems to be in ajax. First of all, use the empty ajax that I have presented to you in the example and check whether the data is coming. then include your own code in your controller.

Comment: "message": "Undefined variable: output" this is the error I got in the controller

Comment: Return response.data with for and print the values ​​one by one.

Comment: same message I am getting is "Undefined variable: output"

Comment: ig: @kaann.gunerr send me TeamViewer id or Anydesk id

Comment: 917492807 anydesk

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your code, double key `'table_data'` and undefined variable `$table_data`
[image]

```
//Jquery
var data = {
    "_token": $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    query:query
};
$.ajax({
        URL:"/action",
        method: 'GET',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
           $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
           $('total-patient-records').text(data.total_data);
        }
})

//controller

$data = array(
  'table_data'   =>  $output,
  'total_data'   =>  $total_row
);

return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

here is the issue in the document-ready method the data variable is used but Never initialize before using it.

The solution in to pass fetch_patients('') an empty string in your method, instead of data (an undefined variable)

Comment: I know that but what's the solution?

Comment: check answer again.

Comment: still not fetching the data

Comment: then this is an issue within your method ... about the data is undefined you have resolved that... please take a look or add a debugger, where the method is doing something else than expected.